# How do I make this function that uses preg_replace() stop filtering out numbers?

Tags: php

For some reason, this code filters out numbers, I have no clue why it does that, if somebody can help me, that would be appreciated.

```
function makeFriendly($string){
    $string = strtolower(trim($string));
    $string = str_replace("'", '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#[^a-z\-]+#', '_', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#_{2,}#', '_', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#_-_#', '-', $string);
    return preg_replace('#(^_+|_+$)#D', '', $string);
}
```

If I now do this:

```
echo makeFriendly('123asd');
```

It only shows 'asd'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$string = preg_replace('#[^a-z\-]+#', '_', $string);` means: 'replace everything that's neither character from a-z range or hyphen with undescore'.

try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z\-]+#', '', $string);
```

Comment: I will, but I found another problem, for some reason the function works on my index.php page, but when I include the function.php file in another document(in another map) it doesn't work anymore and it still replaces all the numbers and stuff. I did include it correctly btw.

Comment: I fixed it with a really bad fix, just renamed the function and put it in another file in the map seemed to be a way around, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why shouldn't it?

```
$string = preg_replace('#[^a-z\-]+#', '_', $string);
                          ^--- NOT
                           ^^^-- a,b,c,....,z
                               ^--- dash
```

So basically, "anything that ISN'T a-z or a dash, replace with underscore".

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesn't filter out a space either and that is what it needs to do besides all the other stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove `$string = preg_replace('#[^a-z\-]+#', '_', $string);`